# CSS styling for the Frontend for the comparison of the products in Laravel 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, laravel

I would like to display the products in the horizontal form as shown under the **Desired Look**, but right now it is displaying in the vertical form as shown under the **Existing look**.

Please see the Desired Look screenshot below:

[image]

**Desired Look code**

*****shop-compare.html*****

```
 <main class="main">
        <div class="page-header breadcrumb-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="breadcrumb">
                    <a href="index.html" rel="nofollow"><i class="fi-rs-home mr-5"></i>Home</a>
                    <span></span> Shop <span></span> Compare
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container mb-80 mt-50">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 m-auto">
                    <h1 class="heading-2 mb-10">Products Compare</h1>
                    <h6 class="text-body mb-40">There are <span class="text-brand">3</span> products to compare</h6>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table text-center table-compare">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="pr_image">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading mw-200">Preview</td>
                                    <td class="row_img"><img src="assets/imgs/shop/product-2-1.jpg" alt="compare-img" /></td>
                                    <td class="row_img"><img src="assets/imgs/shop/product-1-1.jpg" alt="compare-img" /></td>
                                    <td class="row_img"><img src="assets/imgs/shop/product-3-1.jpg" alt="compare-img" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_title">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Name</td>
                                    <td class="product_name">
                                        <h6><a href="shop-product-full.html" class="text-heading">J.Crew Mercantile Women's Short</a></h6>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product_name">
                                        <h6><a href="shop-product-full.html" class="text-heading">Amazon Essentials Women's Tanks</a></h6>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product_name">
                                        <h6><a href="shop-product-full.html" class="text-heading">Amazon Brand - Daily Ritual Wom</a></h6>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_price">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Price</td>
                                    <td class="product_price">
                                        <h4 class="price text-brand">$12.00</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product_price">
                                        <h4 class="price text-brand">$14.00</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product_price">
                                        <h4 class="price text-brand">$15.00</h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_rating">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Rating</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="rating_wrap">
                                            <div class="product-rate d-inline-block">
                                                <div class="product-rating" style="width: 90%"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="rating_num">(121)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="rating_wrap">
                                            <div class="product-rate d-inline-block">
                                                <div class="product-rating" style="width: 90%"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="rating_num">(35)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="rating_wrap">
                                            <div class="product-rate d-inline-block">
                                                <div class="product-rating" style="width: 90%"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="rating_num">(125)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="description">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Description</td>
                                    <td class="row_text font-xs">
                                        <p class="font-sm text-muted">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row_text font-xs">
                                        <p class="font-sm text-muted">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row_text font-xs">
                                        <p class="font-sm text-muted">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_stock">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Stock status</td>
                                    <td class="row_stock"><span class="stock-status in-stock mb-0">In Stock</span></td>
                                    <td class="row_stock"><span class="stock-status out-stock mb-0">Out of stock</span></td>
                                    <td class="row_stock"><span class="stock-status in-stock mb-0">In Stock</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_weight">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Weight</td>
                                    <td class="row_weight">320 gram</td>
                                    <td class="row_weight">370 gram</td>
                                    <td class="row_weight">380 gram</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_dimensions">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Dimensions</td>
                                    <td class="row_dimensions">N/A</td>
                                    <td class="row_dimensions">N/A</td>
                                    <td class="row_dimensions">N/A</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_add_to_cart">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">Buy now</td>
                                    <td class="row_btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fi-rs-shopping-bag mr-5"></i>Add to cart</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row_btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"><i class="fi-rs-headset mr-5"></i>Contact Us</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row_btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fi-rs-shopping-bag mr-5"></i>Add to cart</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pr_remove text-muted">
                                    <td class="text-muted font-md fw-600"></td>
                                    <td class="row_remove">
                                        <a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fi-rs-trash mr-5"></i><span>Remove</span> </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row_remove">
                                        <a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fi-rs-trash mr-5"></i><span>Remove</span> </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="row_remove">
                                        <a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fi-rs-trash mr-5"></i><span>Remove</span> </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Please see the Existing Look screenshot below:

[image]

**Existing Look code**

***view_compare.blade.php***

```
<div class="page-header breadcrumb-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="breadcrumb">
                    <a href="index.html" rel="nofollow"><i class="fi-rs-home mr-5"></i>Home</a>
                     <span></span> Compare
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container mb-80 mt-50">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 m-auto">
                    <h1 class="heading-2 mb-10">Products Compare</h1>
                    <h6 class="text-body mb-40">There are products to compare</h6>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table text-center table-compare">

                            <tbody id="compare">
                                
                               
                            </tbody>
                            
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

***master_dashboard.blade.php***

```
<!--  /// Start Load Compare Data -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    function compare() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/get-compare-product/",

            success:function(response){ 

             $('#compareQty').text(response.compareQty);

             const items = response.compare;

             if (!items.length) {
                $('.table-compare').replaceWith('<p>Nothing to compare</p>');
            }

            const getItemDisplayForRowKey = (item, key) => {
                if (key === 'product_qty') {

                    const isInStock = item.product.product_qty > 0;
                    const className = isInStock ? 'in-stock' : 'out-stock';
                    return `<div class="stock-status ${className} mb-0">${isInStock ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of stock'}</div>`;

                    
                } else if (key === 'product_thambnail') {
                  return `<img src="${item.product.product_thambnail}" style="width:300px; height:300px;">`;
              } else if (key === 'selling_price') {
                return `<div product_price"><h4 class="price text-brand"> AED ${item.product.discount_price || item.product.selling_price}</h4></div>`;
            } else if (key === 'short_descp') {
                return `<div row_text font-xs"><p class="font-sm text-muted">${item.product.short_descp}</p></div>`;
            } else if (key === 'product_name') {
                return `<div><h6><a href="{{ url('product/details/'.$product->id.'/'.$product->product_slug) }}" class="text-heading">${item.product.product_name}</a></h6></div>`;

            }
            return item.product[key];
        }

        const rowHeading = {
            product_thambnail: 'Preview',
            product_name: 'Name',
            product_qty: 'Quantity',
            selling_price: 'Price',
            short_descp: 'Description'
        };

        const html = ['product_thambnail', 'product_name', 'product_qty', 'selling_price', 'short_descp'].map(rowKey => {
            return `
            <tr class="pr_image">
            <td class="text-muted font-sm fw-600 font-heading">${rowHeading[rowKey]}</td>
            ${items.map(item => {
              return `<td>${getItemDisplayForRowKey(item, rowKey)}</td>`
          })}
            </tr>
            `
        });

        const actionsRow = `
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        ${items.map(item => {
          return `
          <td class="row_remove"><a type="submit" class="text-muted" id="${item.id}" onclick="compareRemove(this.id)"><i class="fi-rs-trash mr-5"></i><span>Remove</span></td>`;
      })}
        <tr>
        `;

        $('#compare').html(html + actionsRow);
    }
});
    }

    compare();


      // / End Load Compare Data -->
    
    </script>
```

// Compare Remove Function

```
function compareRemove(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/compare-remove/"+id,

            success:function(data){
                compare();
                     // Start Message 

                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                  toast: true,
                  position: 'top-end',
                  
                  showConfirmButton: false,
                  timer: 3000 
              })
                if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {

                    Toast.fire({
                        type: 'success',
                        icon: 'success', 
                        title: data.success, 
                    })

                }else{

                 Toast.fire({
                    type: 'error',
                    icon: 'error', 
                    title: data.error, 
                })
             }

              // End Message  


         }
     })
    }
```

//Product Details Route

```
Route::get('/product/details/{id}/{slug}', [IndexController::class, 'ProductDetails']);
```

//IndexController

```
public function ProductDetails($id,$slug){

$product = Product::findOrFail($id);

return view('frontend.product.product_details',compact('product'));

 } // End Method
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table structure you are desiring is more complicated than what you are currently rendering. The important part to understand is that for each *row*, you want to display a property of *each* product object. This tells us that we are going to need nested loops. The outer loop will loop through the product attributes and the inner loop will loop through each product.

We can start with an array of keys that will represent our rows. Each key will be a property of the product we wish to render in that row.

If we just wanted to render the value of each product item at its corresponding key, that would be very simple. However, we have cases with specific mapping logic - for example, displaying the `selling_price` or the `discount_price`. Therefore, we are going to use a function to map the product item to the output for a key, encapsulating the specific mapping logic.

We should also include an object to map the row keys to a friendly display value.

Note that in the example code I am providing that I have not included the CSS classes or any other attributes of the HTML. This is just the basic HTML.

```js
const response = {
  compare: [
    {
      product: {
        discount_price: null,
        product_thumbnail: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570913149827-d2ac84ab3f9a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100&q=80',
        product_name: 'Product One',
        product_qty: 5,
        selling_price: 100,
        short_descp: 'A little about Product One'
      }
    },
    {
      product: {
        discount_price: 199,
        product_thumbnail: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570913149827-d2ac84ab3f9a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100&q=80',
        product_name: 'Product Two',
        product_qty: 0,
        selling_price: 200,
        short_descp: 'A little about Product Two'
      }
    }
  ]
}

$('#compareQty').text(response.compareQty);

const getItemDisplayForRowKey = (item, key) => {
  if (key === 'product_qty') {
    return item.product.product_qty > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Stock Out';
  } else if (key === 'product_thumbnail') {
    return `<img src="${item.product.product_thumbnail}">`;
  } else if (key === 'selling_price') {
    return item.product.discount_price || item.product.selling_price;
  }
  
  return item.product[key];
}

const rowHeading = {
  product_thumbnail: '',
  product_name: 'Name',
  product_qty: 'Quantity',
  selling_price: 'Price',
  short_descp: 'Description'
};

const html = ['product_thumbnail', 'product_name', 'product_qty', 'selling_price', 'short_descp'].map(rowKey => {
  return `
    <tr>
      <td>${rowHeading[rowKey]}</td>
      ${response.compare.map(item => {
        return `<td>${getItemDisplayForRowKey(item, rowKey)}</td>`
      })}
    </tr>
  `
});

$('#compare').html(html);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-header breadcrumb-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
      <a href="index.html" rel="nofollow"><i class="fi-rs-home mr-5"></i>Home</a>
      <span></span> Compare
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container mb-80 mt-50">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 m-auto">
      <h1 class="heading-2 mb-10">Products Compare</h1>
      <h6 class="text-body mb-40">There are products to compare</h6>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table text-center table-compare">

          <tbody id="compare"></tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great reply. Can I apply it to my existing code or I have to go as per your code.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: The intention would be for you to replace what is in your `success` handler with the code above in order to have the correct HTML structure. You would need to add your CSS classes after that.

Comment: Thanks, it is working but I want to add the remove button in the table which is as follows, where do I place in the code;  <td class="row_remove">
            <a type="submit" class="text-muted"  id="${value.id}" 
            onclick="compareRemove(this.id)"><i class="fi-rs-trash mr-5"></i> 
            <span>Remove</span> </a>
            </td>

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen What does the `compareRemove` function do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It removes the individual product from the compare list.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: Thanks. Does it result in a completely new HTTP request or do we need to re-render the table on the front-end?

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: An example of removing an item and re-rendering on the front-end can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/12yebcxa/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fiddle it works fine but in my code when I clicked the Remove button it do not remove the item instead it adds the more items because it is unable to get the product id required for the removal. In addition, I have updated master_dashboard.blade.php and added compareRemove function which I have added to my post which you can find above.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: If you are re-fetching your items after the deletion (by calling `compare`) then you do not need that logic to find the index to remove - the item will be removed in the next fetch response. You will, however, need to move the `click` handler outside of `compare`, or it will be repeatedly applied when `compare` is called. https://jsfiddle.net/76484/p3b08ejL/ is an example, but it will not delete items because it does not have a Delete API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the master_dashboard.blade.php and now the delete functionality is working fine. Since we are mapping the items I am not able to target a specific table cell data as everything contains in a single 'td' element. For example, I want to add the class="stock-status in-stock mb-0" for the 'td' containing the "In Stock" text and other styles for the individual td elements. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: You could move the `<td>` rendering to the mapping function and add logic there to apply class names. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/uopxfsrg/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am getting an error as "Undefined variable $id" which I have passed in the respective else if block in the updated master_dashboard blade file which is as follows: else if (key === 'product_name') { return <div><h6><a href="{{ url('product/details/'.$product->id.'/'.$product->product_slug) }}" class="text-heading">${item.product.product_name}</a></h6></div>; } and I have put php code in to the same file as; @php $product = App\Models\Product::findOrFail($id); $id = $product->id /@endphp . Additionally I have added route and controller function please refer

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: You cannot execute PHP code in JavaScript. If you need each product's URL, you would need either to add it to each product in the server response so that it is available to your JavaScript or you could just construct it on the client-side using the `id` and `product_slug`, as I have done here: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/yhqt90de/

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am getting some sort of error in my code which is as follow; compare:1609 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') and code is as follows; if (!items.length) {
                $('.table-compare').replaceWith('<p>Nothing to compare</p>');
            } I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: That would mean that your `response` object does not contain a `compare` property (which we are assigning to the `items` variable). You would need to check your `response` object to see what it contains. The code expects a property `compare` whose value is an array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked the response with console.log(response); just after the success:function(response){  and I got the result as follows; 0: {id: 19, user_id: 3, product_id: 8, created_at: '2023-04-22T06:46:10.000000Z', updated_at: null, …}  length: 6  but still it shows the same error and I don't see the products on the screen.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen: Has the response been changed? It no longer contains a `compare` property? I am not sure if you are changing the response from the server, but if you change the shape of that object, the client-side code will need to be updated to reflect those changes. Assuming the response is a flat array of product objects, you would want your client-side code to look like: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/rvLe7h9q/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, the response has not been changed and I checked with the code as follows; success:function(response){ 

             const items = response.compare;

             console.log(items);

             if (!items.length) {
                $('.table-compare').replaceWith('<p>Nothing to compare</p>');
            } and now I get as undefined.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen What is the response? Please add it to your post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That issue is resolved but now I have to loop through all the table rows of the following element which is <td>${rowHeading[rowKey]}</td>and add specific classes to each of the rowHeading's value. For the 'Name' value of the product_name key, add the class="pr_title" in order to achieve the following <tr class="pr_title"></tr> and similarly for the 'Price' value of the selling_price key, add the class="pr_title" in order to achieve the following <tr class="pr_price"></tr>and so on for other table rows consequently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253292/discussion-between-76484-and-muhammad-yaseen).